# 'worth +noun + ing' or 'worth + for noun + ing'

Tags: prepositions

> It is worth him teaching poor children.

Obviously he does teaching for poor children and it is regarded worth.

but for the same meaning, is it ok to put a preposition at the front of 'him'?

Like

> It is worth for/to/of him teaching poor children.

is this possible and how are they different from each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence is not grammatically correct.

It is worth `A` to do `B`. This means the cost of doing `A` less than the benefit of `B`.

> It is worth the **investment** to **buy a nice suit**.

We can also use the `for` to specify who this phrase pertains to.

> It is worth the effort **for you** to study English everyday.

Lastly we commonly use `it` as a placeholder for the cost generally meaning time, money or effort.

> It is worth **it (the price)** to buy fresh produce.

Edit with an example source:
http://www.nytimes.com/2015/08/09/realestate/keeping-skyscrapers-from-blowing-in-the-wind.html

[image]

Comment: well Im pretty doubtful to your opinion that 1st sentence is wrong. are you sure with it?? I have never heard Infinitive after 'worth'..even it is so, I know people recommend using gerund form after some words like 'worth'..

Comment: "It is worth him teaching poor children." is not grammatically correct. You can say "It is worth teaching poor children.", but this is a general statement. If you'd like to specify "him" then you would need to use "It is worth it (worthwhile) for him to teach poor children."

Comment: These sentences are not correct.  Instead, you should say it's worth his while or it's worthwhile for him to teach poor children.